# How do I make a new clip from in & out points on my sequence in Premiere Pro CC?

Tags: premiere

When I'm editing a sequence in Premiere Pro CC, I want to be able to create a new sequence from my in & out points on the sequence I'm editing.

What's the simplest way of doing that?

Comment: I’ve seen mark clip - X as a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

create new sequence and treat the "old sequence"  as a normal cips & how you import it from projects bin.

\\ Just like you set In/out points for a normal clip.

or watch

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the tracks you want to copy are selected in your timeline. (as in select V1, V2, A1, A2 etc).

Mark In and Out points using <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd>

Press <kbd>;</kbd> to "lift" them out (copies the tracks into your clipboard and deletes them from your timeline).

Press <kbd>cmd + Z</kbd> to undo the delete (the clips will still be in your clipboard).

Press <kbd>cmd + N</kbd> to make a new sequence.

Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept the default sequence settings.

Press <kbd>cmd + V</kbd> to paste the clips in to the new sequence.